# Generating number of Saturdays in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am new to coding and would like help to write a macros code for generating number of Saturdays for each month when first of each month date is listed already as a range in excel file. The file should look like below

```
Month   Weeks
1/1/2016    5
2/1/2016    4
3/1/2016    4
4/1/2016    5
5/1/2016    4
6/1/2016    4
7/1/2016    5
8/1/2016    4
9/1/2016    4
10/1/2016   5
11/1/2016   4
12/1/2016   4
```

Comment: Can you not just use the weekdays formula to determine the day of the week and then do a countif column = Saturday

Comment: @Lowpar Probably don't need a countif.  By finding the date of the first Saturday in the month, subtracting that from the number of days in the month, and dividing by 7, you should be able to get the answer in a single (simple?) calculation.

Comment: Or sumproduct: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(A2 & ":" & EOMONTH(A2,0))),1)=7))`

Comment: Potential *X-Y Problem* (solving X when real problem is Y) alert: **If** you're counting *full weeks* (running Sunday-Saturday) **and** you're on a 4-5-4 retail calendar (see [NRF calendar](https://nrf.com/resources/4-5-4-calendar)), then no worksheet function can help you, and counting the number of Saturdays in a month won't help you either; the solution is to know which `MonthOfQuarter` you're in - number of weeks is always consistent between quarters, i.e. months 1 and 3 have 4 weeks, month 2 has 5 weeks. Well then there's the odd 53-week year to account for, but your calendar data has it.

Comment: Of course if the NRF calendar is irrelevant, please ignore above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.  You will need to add Sheets("SheetName") in front of the Cells.

```
Sub CountSaturdays()

    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To LR
        StDt = Cells(x, 1)
        EndDt = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Cells(x, 1), 0)
            For Dt = StDt To EndDt
                If WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Dt) = 7 Then
                    Sat = Sat + 1
                End If
            Next Dt
        Cells(x, 2) = Sat
        Sat = 0
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: There actually is a native VBA Weekday function; no need to use the WorksheetFunction. EoMonth could be dateserial(year(cells(2, "A")), month(cells(2, "A"))+1, 0)

Answer (score 6):

I'm unclear on why you require VBA for this.

As a worksheet formula,

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2, EOMONTH(A2, 0), "1111101")
```

Comment: I always forget about that third string.

Comment: Yeah, you have to go to the [networkdays.intl](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-INTL-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28) page for a good description. The built-in Excel help doesn't even mention it.

Comment: btw, you can add a holiday list to networkdays.intl as well.

Comment: btw², my calendar shows **5** Saturdays in Dec-2016.